# Unload/remove dynamically loaded css files

Tags: css, dom, vue.js, webpack, css-loader

After loading a css file like this:

```
const themes = ['dark-theme.css', 'light-theme.css'];
async function loadcss(file) {
    return await import(file);
}
loadcss(themes[0]).then(console.log)
```

The console output is an empty object for me and a new annonymous < style> tag sits in the < head> of my index.html. So far so good, but what if I (in this example) want to change the theme to *light-theme.css*. That would merge both themes as *dark-theme.css* is already loaded.

Is there a way to **remove** the < style> tag from the DOM?

To furthermore specify my question, the provided example shows an abstracted behaviour and I am only interested in removing the dynamically loaded css from the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know vue.js but here is simple example in React hope it helps somehow :) perhaps some ideas at least :)

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  static themes = {
    dark: 'dark-theme.css', 
    light: 'light-theme.css',
  };

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        (<link rel="stylesheet" href={TodoApp.themes.dark} type="text/css"></link>),
      document.head
    );  
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3y4hw2ox/

Comment: Thank you, it already gave me an idea. Writing my question, I thought of a pure javascript approach, but leveraging Components and their DOM control is worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to OZZIE, I questioned my methodology and found, that importing the css files, like my question shows (through ES6 import, or require.context(...)), is not usefull, as we can't identify it, we dont get access to the `<style>` element, leaving us with no entry to the DOM and no way to manipulate it.

Instead we will link the css files manually in the `<head>`, as we know their name and path.

```
const themes = ['dark-theme.css', 'light-theme.css'];
const head = document.body.parentElement.firstElementChild;
const link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('href', process.env.BASE_URL + themes[0]);
link.setAttribute('id', themes[0]); // set id so we can remove it later
head.appendChild(link);
```